# Spring MVC - Hit to URL with RequestParam failing with 404 Not Found Error

Tags: spring, web-services, rest, spring-mvc

I am using Spring MVC in my project and while mapping user request to a URI, I get the 404 error. Here is my function skeleton which I want to be invoked:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/inventory/discovery", method = RequestMethod.GET, params = {"discoveryType"}, produces = {"application/json"})
public String getDiscoveryByType(@RequestParam("discoveryType") String discoveryType)  
{
    return discoveryType;
}
```

I am expecting this method to be called when I give the URL

```
 http://<some-ip>/inventory/discovery/discoveryType?=DMVPN
```

However, when I test the code using Chrome's Advanced Rest Client I see that the URI it is trying to access is "/inventory/DMVPN" and not the "/inventory/discovery?discoveryType=DMVPN".

Am I missing something here?  I don't see anything wrong with my URL syntax

I have another function in my code (but I don't think it is causing the problem) which has same request-mapping value, but has no params attribute.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/inventory/discovery", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = { "application/json" })
public ResponseEntity<DiscoveryNIOListResult> getAllDiscovery() {
    logger.trace("getAllDiscovery");
    List<DiscoveryNIO> listDiscoveryNIO = discoveryDasClient.getDiscoveryList();
    DiscoveryNIOListResult result = new DiscoveryNIOListResult();
    result.setResponse(listDiscoveryNIO);
    return new ResponseEntity<DiscoveryNIOListResult>(result, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Comment: If you are deploying this as a WAR then you are missing the context part of the URL, which is usually the WAR name unless you set it otherwise.

Comment: Is this something needed in case of using RequestParam only? Because I am able to invoke second method using the URL: http://10.104.105.127:8089/inventory/discovery. No context is involved here.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so a second look at your URL:

```
http://<some-ip>/inventory/discovery/discoveryType?=DMVPN
```

This is NOT passing discoveryType as a request GET parameter.  For that you would need to do:

```
http://<some-ip>/inventory/discovery&discoveryType?=DMVPN
```

If you want to use path variables instead, you could do something like:

```
http://<some-ip>/inventory/discovery/DMVPN
```

And change your handler to something like:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/inventory/discovery/{discoveryType}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = {"application/json"})
public String getDiscoveryByType(@PathVariable("discoveryType") String discoveryType)  
{
    return discoveryType;
}
```

It looks like you were trying to mix these two methods, and that wont work.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your URL to:

```
http://<some-ip>/inventory/discovery?discoveryType=DMVPN
```